# Переименовать тэг в XML

Tags: xml, c#

Как переименовать корневой тэг?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Загрузите XML в string и используйте `string.Replace('old_root_tag','new_root_tag')`

UPD: [[@VladD](/users/10105/vladd)](/users/10105/vladd) абсолютно прав.

Тогда примерно так:

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.Load("путь_к_вашей_xml");
XmlElement root = xmlDoc.DocumentElement;
root.InnerText = "новое_имя";
xmlDoc.Save("путь_к_новой_xml");
```

Comment: Эээ, это грязное решение.

Что, если XML выглядит так

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
    <!-- honeypot: <old_root_tag> -->
    <old_root_tag>
    <old_root_tag/>

?

Comment: @VladD, вы правы.

Comment: О, парсер, теперь +1.

Comment: Но всё же надо не `InnerText`, а создать новый узел:

    XmlElement newRoot = xmlDoc.CreateElement("новое_имя");
    foreach (XmlNode child in root.ChildNodes)
        newRoot.AppendChild(child.CloneNode(true));
    xmlDoc.ReplaceChild(newRoot, root);

Comment: @VladD, вы опять-таки правы. Пятница все-таки, туплю :)

Comment: Спасибо большое ребята.VladD, чем вариант без клонирования лучше первого?

Comment: Есть еще одна проблема. Попытаюсь объяснить вообще что делаю: есть выгрузки в формате xml, первый корневой тег <ArrayOfStaffEntry xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" version="1.4.12.0" xmlns="StaffEntry"> со своим пространством имен xmlns="StaffEntry". В этот тег входит список из множества тегов <StaffEntry>. Мне нужно сформировать запрос для SOAP (веб-сервис).Внутри запроса мне нужно сделать тег <staff> ОБЯЗАТЕЛЬНО c пространством имен xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" и в тег <staff> перетащить все <StaffEntry>

Comment: То есть, у меня сейчас практически все так, за исключением отсутствия xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" у тега <staff>

Comment: посмотрите в сторону 
   doc.CreateElement("имя_элемента", doc.DocumentElement.NamespaceURI).

Comment: @Макс Жуков doc.CreateElement добавляет тег в конец, а не подскажете как в начало сделать?

Comment: @YGOR-CHAMIN: Ну, пособирайте по комментариям, у вас же уже весь код есть.

    XmlElement newRoot = xmlDoc.CreateElement("новое_имя",  doc.DocumentElement.NamespaceURI);
    ...
    xmlDoc.ReplaceChild(newRoot, root);

Answer (score 0):

Решение в лоб - с помощью подстрок, нашел подстроку - заменил (от второго < до пробела и в конце)